# how to install conflicting packages?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have both `anaconda` for `python 2.7` and for `python 3` installed on my machine.

I am trying to install `user-agents` (https://github.com/selwin/python-user-agents) and I get the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\john>conda install user-agents
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - user-agents
  - zict
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I have looked at the FAQ https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html but I do not understand how to avoid this issue. Running the `-info` command on both packages shows

```
(base) C:\Users\john>conda info user-agents

user-agents 1.1.0 py27_0
------------------------
file name   : user-agents-1.1.0-py27_0.tar.bz2
name        : user-agents
version     : 1.1.0
build string: py27_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
size        : 16 KB
arch        : x86_64
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
md5         : 98e6b4d286813445d0a2f222ca3f08fa
platform    : win32
subdir      : win-64
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/user-agents-1.1.0-py27_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    python 2.7*
    ua-parser >=0.4.1

user-agents 1.0.1 py34_0
------------------------
file name   : user-agents-1.0.1-py34_0.tar.bz2
name        : user-agents
version     : 1.0.1
build string: py34_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
size        : 12 KB
arch        : x86_64
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
md5         : 960c836c6c8fd5e7a126c15b39be5d35
platform    : win32
subdir      : win-64
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/user-agents-1.0.1-py34_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    python 3.4*
    ua-parser >=0.4.1

user-agents 1.0.1 py27_1
------------------------
file name   : user-agents-1.0.1-py27_1.tar.bz2
name        : user-agents
version     : 1.0.1
build string: py27_1
build number: 1
channel     : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
size        : 13 KB
arch        : x86_64
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
md5         : 9c829288911183766ddaa741f537b6ca
platform    : win32
subdir      : win-64
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/user-agents-1.0.1-py27_1.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    python 2.7*
    ua-parser >=0.4.1

user-agents 1.0.1 py27_0
------------------------
file name   : user-agents-1.0.1-py27_0.tar.bz2
name        : user-agents
version     : 1.0.1
build string: py27_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
size        : 12 KB
arch        : x86_64
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
md5         : 5f8bff4eecc0921d8ff6637c5214a69d
platform    : win32
subdir      : win-64
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/user-agents-1.0.1-py27_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    python 2.7*
    ua-parser >=0.4.1

user-agents 1.0.1 py34_1
------------------------
file name   : user-agents-1.0.1-py34_1.tar.bz2
name        : user-agents
version     : 1.0.1
build string: py34_1
build number: 1
channel     : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
size        : 13 KB
arch        : x86_64
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
md5         : 968c308d3f28527d010ab1ea7e08f043
platform    : win32
subdir      : win-64
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/user-agents-1.0.1-py34_1.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    python 3.4*
    ua-parser >=0.4.1
```

Can someone please tell me what is the correct `conda` command here?
Thanks!

Comment: You should include the output for `conda info zict`, from which you can determine what is the exact conflict and what you would have to do to resolve.

Comment: the list if very long, essentially it shows many different `zict` packages each having dependencies `heapdict` and python (from 2.7 to 3.6)

Comment: I wonder if this is only a matter of specifying exactly which version of the package is need (and perhaps for which python env). I dont know how to do that in `conda` though

Comment: Specifying version is [mentioned in the docs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages), e.g. `conda install user-agents=1.1.0`

Comment: Also, you should mention the version of `zict` that is already installed on your system.

Comment: *I have both anaconda for python 2.7 and for python 3 installed on my machine.* Do you mean you have two versions of Anaconda? I don't think this is advised, and neither is installing new stuff into the `base` environment. Have one Anaconda installation, the latest version, and create separate environments for each Python version and combination of packages you want to work with.

Comment: why is this not advised? what is the issue? these are installed in separate directories

Comment: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/ says: *Anaconda2 includes Python 2.7 and Anaconda3 includes Python 3.6. However, it does not matter which one you download, because you can create new environments that include any version of Python packaged with `conda`.* There's no need to have more than one installation and it may mess up paths and so on if you do.